# Include images from my GeoJSON feed into the tooltip with mapbox?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I am trying to display images from my GeoJSON feed onto the tooltips.

I am referencing a script that displays custom images in the tooltips (but not from a geojson feed). So I am trying to combine the two, but I am at a loss for what to do. Been reading through the mapbox and LeafletJS API docs.

Any advice or solutions is much appreciated.

What I have:

```
// for clickable coords //

var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');

// dark map example + set views //

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-y7l23tes')
    .setView([40.70319876407339, -74.03961181640625], 12);
    L.control.locate().addTo(map);


// click to add coords //

    map.on('click', function(e) {
    window[e.type].innerHTML = e.containerPoint.toString() + ', ' + e.latlng.lng.toString()+ ' XsupX ' + e.latlng.lat.toString();

    latitude.value = e.latlng.lat.toString();
    longitude.value = e.latlng.lng.toString();

    var click = document.getElementById('click'); });


// grip JSON //

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('/locations.json')
    .addTo(map);
```

The script I am referencing that includes custom images, but without GeoJSON feed as a source for the images.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-9ijuk24y');

var geoJson = [{
    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-77.03, 38.90]},
    "properties": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg/320px-Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg",
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.",
        "marker-symbol": "star",
        "city": "Washington, D.C."
    }
}, {
    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-87.63, 41.88]},
    "properties": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Chicago_sunrise_1.jpg/640px-Chicago_sunrise_1.jpg",
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago",
        "city": "Chicago"
    }
}, {
    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-74.00, 40.71]},
    "properties": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/NYC_Top_of_the_Rock_Pano.jpg/640px-NYC_Top_of_the_Rock_Pano.jpg",
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City",
        "city": "New York City"
    }
}];

// Add custom popups to each using our custom feature properties
map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;

    // Create custom popup content
    var popupContent =  '<a target="_blank" class="popup" href="' + feature.properties.url + '">' +
                            '<img src="' + feature.properties.image + '">' +
                        '   <h2>' + feature.properties.city + '</h2>' +
                        '</a>';

    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 320
    });
});

// Add features to the map
map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

map.setView([45.908, -78.525], 4);
```

Update: a more simple approach...

```
    var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [{
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
                title: location.title,
                image: location.image,
            },
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [0, 0]
            }
        }]
    })
    .loadURL('http://localhost:3000/locations.json')
    .addTo(map);


featureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {

    // here you call `bindPopup` with a string of HTML you create - the feature
    // properties declared above are available under `layer.feature.properties`

    var content = '<h1>size: ' + location.title + '<\/h1>' +
         '<img src="' + location.image + '">';
    layer.bindPopup(content);
});
```

Comment: I found an article of someone doing something similar here : "http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/rob-decker/map-your-locations-mapbox". He accomplished it through ajax. Definitely some hints in here I am following. I will post some updated code soon.

Comment: i'm experimenting with this... http://jsfiddle.net/jvSMA/ Thinking that maybe all I need to do is set up the "function that returns html to be used in tooltip" correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for me was... I had to wrap all the content I wanted within the AJAX call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(geojson) {
        // Fetch just the contents of a .geojson file from ... by passing
        // `......` to the Accept header
        // As with any other AJAX request, this technique is subject to the Same Origin Policy:
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy the server delivering the request should support CORS.
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'localhost'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/locations.json',
            success: function (geojson) {

                // setting URL for json call below.
                // var url = '/locations.json';
                // initializing map, dark theme, and view.

                var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-y7l23tes')
                    .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('examples.map-y7l23tes'))
                    .setView([40.7178591652903, -73.985538482666], 12);
                // Add custom popups to each using our custom feature properties
                map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function (e) {

                    var marker = e.layer,
                        feature = marker.feature;
                    // Create custom popup content
                    var popupContent = '<div class="popup">' + '<img src="' + feature.properties.image.image.url + '">' +
                        '<p style="font-size:94%">' + feature.properties.user_id + ' posted: ' +
                        '<p>' + feature.properties.title + '</p>' +
                        '<p><span class="timeago" title="' + feature.properties.created_at + '"></span></p>' +
                        '<% if can? :update, @location %><p><a href="/locations/' + feature.properties.name + '/edit">Edit</a> <% end %>' +
                        '<% if can? :destroy, @location %> | <%= link_to "Destroy", @location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %><% end %>';

                    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
                    return marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
                        closeButton: false,
                        minWidth: 320
                    });
                });

                // Iterate through each feature layer item, build a
                // marker menu item and enable a click event that pans to + opens
                // a marker that's associated to the marker item.
                map.featureLayer.eachLayer(function (marker) {
                    var link = info.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
                    link.className = 'item';
                    link.href = '#';

                    // Populate content from each markers object.
                    link.innerHTML = '<img src="' + marker.feature.properties.image.image.url + '" style="width:50px; height:auto;">' + marker.feature.properties.title +
                        '<br /><small>' + marker.feature.properties.user_id + '</small>';
                    link.onclick = function () {
                        if (/active/.test(this.className)) {
                            this.className = this.className.replace(/active/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                        } else {
                            var siblings = info.getElementsByTagName('a');
                            for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
                                siblings[i].className = siblings[i].className
                                    .replace(/active/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                            };
                            this.className += ' active';

                            // When a menu item is clicked, animate the map to center
                            // its associated marker and open its popup.
                            map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
                            marker.openPopup();
                        }
                        return false;
                    };
                });
            }
        });
    }
    $(load);
</script>
```